# How to add a key to my DRF API response value

Tags: python-2.7, django-rest-framework

My API returns just the value. I believe it's my fault but am not very versatile with Python/Django. Any help is appreciated.

**What is returned**

```
"This is the message"
```

**What I want**:

```
{
    "message": "This is a message"
}
```

All I want to do is to add a word as a `key`

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

from id.models import Id
from rest_framework import generics
from id.serializers import IdSerializer
from django.http import Http404
from IPython import embed


class OfferView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = IdSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'

    def get_queryset(self):
        id = self.kwargs['id']
        try:
            return Id.objects.filter(id=id)
        except Mamo.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()

        serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)
        try:
            if serializer.data[0]['offer_id'] is not None:
                result = serializer.data[0]['main_offer']
            elif serializer.data[0]['offer_id'] is None:
                result = serializer.data[0]['extra_offer']
            else:
                result = serializer.data[0]['exceptional_offer']
            return Response(result)
        except IndexError:
            raise Http404
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change

> **Note:** The thing is what you will form that you will get, you were just returning `string` and that was the problem. Now let's convert that to a dictionary (more specifically the JSON here in REST).
>
> **serializer.data** is a dictionary. You can form a single dictionary containing the keys & values (JSON serializable) you want.  Here I just tried to fulfill the need.

```
result = serializer.data[0]['exceptional_offer']
```

to

```
result = {"message": serializer.data[0]['exceptional_offer']}
```

and the similar for others as well.

**Better way:**

Just change the following (last lines, I mean `try...except`)

```
try:
    if serializer.data[0]['offer_id'] is not None:
        result = serializer.data[0]['main_offer']
    elif serializer.data[0]['offer_id'] is None:
        result = serializer.data[0]['extra_offer']
    else:
        result = serializer.data[0]['exceptional_offer']
    return Response(result)
except IndexError:
    raise Http404
```

to the below one (writing the same piece of code is like code duplication).

```
try:
    if serializer.data[0]['offer_id'] is not None:
        # result = serializer.data[0]['main_offer']
        key = 'main_offer'
    elif serializer.data[0]['offer_id'] is None:
        # result = serializer.data[0]['extra_offer']  
        key = 'extra_offer'
    else:
        # result = serializer.data[0]['exceptional_offer']
        key = 'exceptional_offer'

    result = {'message': serializer.data[0][key]}
    return Response(result)
except IndexError:
    raise Http404
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out am just returning the `result` and not creating a JSON Object.

Adding `result = {'message': serializer.data[0]…}` to all the variable `result` in the `if..else` conditions solves it for me.